# How to set a foreign key of my primary key in EF core

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

Lets imagine I have an entity **Car** and I'm setting up a table to replace cars when one is not available, lets call it **CarSwap** witch is just a table with 2 columns, one with the CarId we have and the other the CarId that replaces it.

```
Class CarSwap{
  public int CarId { get; set; }
  public int ReplacerId { get; set; }
  public Car Car { get; set; }
}
```

2 cars might be replaced by the same car,
but one car can only be replaced by one car

so I thought the code to represent this would be:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CarSwap> builder)
{
   builder.HasKey(c => new { c.CarId }); // Key because one car can only be replaced by one car
   builder.Property(c => c.CarId ).ValueGeneratedNever();

   builder.HasOne(e => e.Car).WithOne().HasForeignKey(typeof(CarSwap), "CarId").IsRequired();
   builder.HasOne(e => e.Car).WithMany().HasForeignKey(a => a.ReplacerId).IsRequired(); // Because the replacer can replace multiple cars
}
```

When generating the migration, this codes creates the correct foreign key for ReplacerId but not for CarId.

How do I make it generate the proper foreign key so that it doesn't allow me to add cars that don't exist?

Answer (score 0):

Now I've realised my silly mistake. I had no object to map the replaced car.
Iv've fixed it by changing it to:

```
Class CarSwap{
  public int CarId { get; set; }
  public int ReplacerId { get; set; }
  public Car Car { get; set; }
  public Car Replacer { get; set; }
}
```

and then changed:

```
builder.HasOne(e => e.Car).WithMany().HasForeignKey(a => a.ReplacerId).IsRequired(); // Because the replacer can replace multiple cars
```

to:

```
builder.HasOne(e => e.Replacer).WithMany().HasForeignKey(a => a.ReplacerId).IsRequired(); // Because the replacer can replace multiple cars
```